# How to grab the rest of the string too in the regex matches?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following string:

```
this is a test string user:testuser,anotheruser hashtag:peach,phone,milk site:youtube.com,twitter.com flair:bobby
```

Currently the regex `([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)` matches all the filters with colon in between (user, hashtag, site, flair). How can I also grab the remaining `"this is a test string"` part as another match?

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/L0T2GJ/11

Comment: Maybe `/^.*?(?=\s+[^:\s]+:)|([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxsatL/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does seem to match the initial string but then it doesn't match the user, hashtag and site as groups (group 1 being the before colon part and group 2 being the after colon part) as it does with my original query.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/AxsatL/1, or this - https://regex101.com/r/AxsatL/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! Works perfectly. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Without lookahead you could just append an alternation: [`([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)|^(?:[^:\s]+\s)*`](https://regex101.com/r/x4JgKg/1) with the disadvantage that the first match won't be trimmed to the right (whitespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an alternative to match any 0+ chars as few as possible from the start of the string till the first key followed with a colon:

```
^.*?(?=\s+[^:\s]+:)|([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxsatL/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
  -`.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+[^:\s]+:)` - the positive lookahead makes sure that, immediately to the right of the current position, there is

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^:\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `:` and whitespace
  - `:` - a colon